# Excel VBA function can't set range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've written a VBA function that takes two parameters, the first is a string and the 2nd is a range, specified in the sheet as:

```
=strPack(B1,G3)
```

In the code, this routine is declared as:

```
Public Function strPack(ByVal strHex As String, ByRef rngCnt As Range) As String
    On Error Goto ErrHandler
    If False Then
ErrHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim intCnt As Integer
    intCnt = 0
    '...do something with strHex and increment intCnt whilst we go
    rngCnt.Value = CStr(intCnt)
    'strPack is populated by the body of the function
    strPack = "Hello World"
End Function
```

I've tried .Value, .Value2 and .Text, all result in an error:

```
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

When I look in the debugger, both strHex and rngCnt are valid and correct.  Why can't I assign to the range and how do I fix it?

The error handler is not the problem, try it out, it works perfectly well and is a standard way of picking up errors and aborting a function when an error occurs.

[Edit]  I've just tried the following:

```
Public Sub updateCount()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value = CStr(intProcessed)
End Sub
```

intProcessed is global to the module and is an integer, result is the same, exactly the same error.

[Edit2] I want to remove this post as I've changed the approach now to call another subroutine that returns a value which is dropped into the cell.  I can't delete it! Thank you to all for your help.

Comment: Beyond everything else that is wrong, a UDF on the worksheet cannot change the value of another cell. It can only return a value to the cell it resides in.

Comment: @urdearboy, False is a constant defined in VBA, this is a stand way of error handling, when an error occurs it jumps to the label ErrHandler.

Comment: @user10735198, this is not what the very many online examples say or demonstrate.

Comment: First, you might want to add `VBA` tag to this post as your question is related to `VBA`. Issue I can see with your code is that you have your `ErrHandler` in your `IF` statement. As far as I am aware, you cannot do that. When you set `On Error Goto ErrHandler`, you are telling the compiler to go there if there is an error. You cannot then have that place in the middle of an `IF` condition as now you have a situation where there is an `End If` without an `IF`

Comment: @Zac, yes you can, the error handler is not a problem, I've done this since 2005.

Comment: @urdearboy, that isn't the actual code just a quick sample to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The error is encountered as soon as the debugger hits the line: rngCnt.Value = CStr(intCnt)

Comment: I would like to see where you find that a UDF called from the worksheet can effect a different cell from the one that called the UDF.  Everything I have read and learned is that it cannot be done and for good reason.

Comment: Now you can call a sub from the function and have the sub do the changing, but the UDF by itself cannot do that.  See: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/how-to-change-another-cell-with-a-vba-function-udf/

Comment: @ScottCraner, why not? I can see no reason for this.

Comment: @SPlatten you are asking me why Microsoft set a policy?  I can only guess that it is a method to help maintain data integrity.  Currently you know where every value comes from.  If the data changes unexpectedly then you can trace it back to the source, but if cells were allowed to change the values of others, then knowing what and why gets complicated.  You have to find the cell that is doing it and that can be an arduous task.

Comment: I just added a subroutine to try it out and I get exactly the same result.

Comment: @urdearboy, sorry I can't.

Comment: I get no error on your edited sub.  when I set intprocessed as 10.  When you get the error, what is the value of that variable?

Comment: Same @ScottCraner. OP, If you can't share your code, you will need to create a code you can share that produces the same error. The code needs to be *minimal, complete, and reproducible*

Comment: What is the point of `CStr()` when assigning a value to a cell? Excel will convert it to an integer anyway, unless the cell is formatted as text -- in which case `CStr()` is superfluous.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I try to be type correct and not rely on implied behaviour by the application.

Comment: @SPlatten Okay, that makes sense, but it could also lead to errors if you inadvertently rely on the application to take your type hints into account.

Comment: I want to close it as I've changed my original code to use an alternative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the code comments:

```
Public Function strPack(ByVal strHex As String, ByVal rngCnt As Range) As String

   Dim lRes     As Long

   On Error GoTo errHandler

     lRes = 1000 '==> Your business logic goes here

     '/ This is the gymnastics you do to update range from an UDF
     Application.Evaluate ("UpdateRange(" & rngCnt.Address & "," & lRes & ")")
     strPack = "SUCCESSFULL"

errHandler:
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strPack = "FAILED"
   End If

End Function

'/ Helper to allow range update from UDF
Private Function UpdateRange(rngDest As Range, val As Variant)
    rngDest.Value = val
End Function
```

Comment: In what way is this different from my own example?  rngDest is passed over by reference and assigned in the same way...it won't work.

Comment: calm down. Read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Perhaps its the version of Excel I'm using its 2010.

Comment: @SPlatten I've previously used this method in Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 - however, as with all UDFs, you need to make sure that the code is in a **Module**, not in a **Sheet Object**.

Comment: @Chronocidal, the code is in a module, not a sheet. Thank you.